# I'm confused about why in this limit function that it is 0 instead of undefined/divergent.

Tags: calculus

I was trying to solve this improper integral, and I got a limit which I thought was undefined, but the book key says it isn't. The integral is
$$\int_{0}^{1} x \, \ln x \, dx.$$

I obtained the limit $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t \, \ln(t)}{2}.$$

I don't understand why the limit goes to zero.

Comment: Replace $t$ with $1/u$ and let $u$ tend to $+\infty$.

Comment: Replace $t$ with $e^{-x}$ and let $x$ tends to $+\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is true that as $t\to 0$, we have $t\to 0$ and $\log t\to -\infty$, creating a $0\cdot \infty$ intererminacy. However, $t$ goes to zero much faster that $\log t$ goes to infinity, so $0$ wins.

One quick way to see this is to apply L'Hospitale's rule: write $t\log t=-\frac{-\log t}{1/t}$, so that both numerator and denominator tend to $+\infty$, and observe
$$
\lim_{t\to 0+}\frac{(-\log t)'}{(1/t)'}=
\lim_{t\to 0+}\frac{-1/t}{-1/t^2}=\lim_{t\to 0+} t=0.
$$

An intuitive explanation is this: let us plug $t/2$ instead of $t$ into the expression. We have $\log \frac{t}{2}=\log t - \log 2.$ So, while $1/t$ increased by a *factor* of two, $-\log t$ increased by a *constant* $\log 2$. When $t$ is small, both $1/t$ and $-\log t$ are large, so increasing by a factor of $2$ is much better than increasing by a constant. So, as $t\to 0$, $1/t$ grows faster than $-\log t$.